# Deleting an item from viewholder

Tags: android, listview, layout-inflater

I am using viewHolder and Layout Inflater for my listview. I have implemented on click even on the image that is displayed in my listview. I just want to know that how can I delete an entire row using the holder because I am unable to use the `remove()` function.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rows in `ListView`/`RecyclerView`s are deleted by removing that element from the `Adapter` and then updating the `ListView`/`RecyclerView` with `notifyDataSetChanged()`